# CSS set font to "strong"

Tags: css

I need to set the font to "strong", but can't work out how to do this with CSS? I tried

```css
font-weight: 'Strong';
```

And I also tried it without the marks and it didn't work either. I'd like to set it to strong and not just bold as I've heard it helps disabled people while they are browsing your website (but that may be rubbish?!)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/CSS_Reference

Answer (score 24):

You probably mean:

```css
font-weight: bold;
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no `strong` weight, try `bold` (which is usually the default browser style for a `<strong>` element.

[more about `font-weight` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-weight)

Answer (score 4):

I just solved this exact problem based off the post I read here. Bold is not what you want as bold is not the equivalent of strong.

For me using a polymer custom component.

Strong = `font-weight: 400`

Bold starts at `font-weight: 500` or greater.

Looking into it a bit further reveals that this is dependant on browser version and display and sometimes things don't get rendered how you want.

More details can be found at the MDN link posted above by steveax and Ryan

Answer (score 2):

`bold` is the only way. You're confusing the accessibility aspect with the *HTML tags* `<b>` and `<strong>`, which have a bold style by default.

`<b>` versus `<strong>` has less to do with accessibility, too, and more to do with semantics and the separation of styles from content. After all, you can style all `<b>` tags to be non-bold, and that’s just confusing.

Comment: I think I may very well be. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

font-weight:bold; is the equivalent of 'strong' font. You can also try

font-weight:900; (using numeric values).

Answer (score -2):

strong is a html tag. css is for visual.